# Why my map app crashes if I set maxSdkVersion in the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Tags: android, maps, android-permissions

I've set my map following the instructions in [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2). And set the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in accordance with the recomended by the [Official Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html), that is request this permission only for API level 18 and lower. So, I have this manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.HomeActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/map_api_key"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But I am facing this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following
permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But, as it is showed in my manifest, I have this permission. One detail is if I put only the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, without specifying the `maxSdkVersion` value, the app works properly.

Is this an Android bug or am I forgetting something in my app configuration?

**UPDATE 1**

This is the logcat:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.map, PID: 15534
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.map/com.example.map.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
    at com.example.map.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    at maps.e.ci.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.e.bh.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.e.bg.a(Unknown Source)
    at etu.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1093)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1195)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
```

**UPDATE 2**

My layout:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your min SDK version? Please show XML.

Comment: It is 8. I am using AndroidStudio, so the the version is set in the build.gradle

Comment: Are you using the same XML shown in link?

Comment: yes. exactly this one.

Comment: Show me the XML and code.

Comment: I've updated the question. My activity has only onCreate method, which set the content view for the layout showed in the question. And it extends from ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Show me your fragment code.

Comment: I don't have fragment. This one used in the code is from the Google Play Services lib.

Comment: Show me your Mainactivity.java

Answer (score 3):

If you check the link you've provided to the [`<uses-permission>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) documentation, you'll see that it states that:

> it's no longer necessary for your app to request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission when your app wants to write to its *own application-specific directories* on external storage (the directories provided by `getExternalFilesDir()`).

It would appear that the Maps API needs write access to other directories. And if you check the [Specify permissions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_permissions) section of the other link you gave, it still lists the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission as required, with no mention of exception for API Level 19.

---

After having checked many, many online resources with regard to the Maps API, Android API Level 19, and the restriction of the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, I found no source or example that listed or referenced a working example using the Maps API with that permission restricted to API Level 18 and below. Again, I quote the link you've provided that says the permission is not needed in API Level 19 "when your app wants to write to its *own application-specific directories on external storage*".  (I would point out that it merely says it is not necessary in that case, and in no way "recommends" that you set this restriction absolutely.) The Maps API *needs* write-permission to external storage directories that are *not owned by your app*. The fact that "without specifying the `maxSdkVersion` value, the app works properly" indicates that even in KitKat, Maps needs that permission. The error is telling you exactly that.

Comment: The two links are independent. The last one focuses on map implementation, so they don't spend time giving information about api exceptions. And the complete sentence given by my link says that it's not necessary thnis permission for API 19.

Comment: I don't specify maxSdkVersion for my app, this is not recomended by Android, I just specify max sdk for the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: It would be nice if Maps API had a configuration method that would let you request that it only read/write a new cache directory under your own application-specific directory, but I'm not aware of such a feature yet. (That would of course mean it could not reuse cached tiles it had already downloaded, but some users may be fine with giving that up for the ability to request a fewer number of permissions.)

Answer (score 1):

I did some research around the maxSdkVersion. And I found the following

From google
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

> Warning: Declaring this attribute is not recommended. First, there is no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully backward-compatible. Your application should work properly on new versions, provided it uses only standard APIs and follows development best practices. Second, note that in some cases, declaring the attribute can result in your application being removed from users' devices after a system update to a higher API Level. Most devices on which your application is likely to be installed will receive periodic system updates over the air, so you should consider their effect on your application before setting this attribute.

I have something like this in my current working google app

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

So if you really want, you can try put that maxSdkVersion in the  note, unless its what google is documented in the above link.

Hope this help

Comment: The maxSdkVersion mentioned by you, is an attribute of the <uses-sdk> tag, and it is used to "designating the maximum API Level on which the application is designed to run", and really this is not recommended. The maxSdkVersion mentioned by me is an attribute of the <uses-permission> tag, and it is used to "setting the highest API level at which this permission should be granted to your app".

Answer (score 0):

The XML code provided in the link is for Android API 12 or later.
Since your minSDKVersion is 8. Use this:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Check [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/) for more.

Comment: Sorry. I am using this layout. The error happens yet

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: Instead of ActionBarActivity if you use FragmentActivity, what is the output?